# python 2d list adding and replace element

Tags: list, python-3.x, replace

```
2d_list = [[1,0],[2,0],[3,0]]
```

gets a input `num` from user and added to the first element and saves the result in 2nd element and replace the first list

Enter a Integer number: 2

output: `[[1,3], [2, 4], [3,5]]`

Comment: Why are you using a list to do this? Look at the [counter class](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=counter#collections.Counter)

Answer (score 1):

```
myList = [[1,0],[2,0],[3,0]]
num = int(raw_input("Enter a number: "))
newList = [[i[0], i[0]+num] for i in myList]
```

This might be faster (due to not allocating new space):

```
myList = [[1,0],[2,0],[3,0]]
num = int(raw_input("Enter a number: "))
for elem in myList:
    elem[1] = elem[0]+num
```